# Adding a mailto as valid url

Tags: html, wordpress, url, mailto

Recently I've gotten a wordpress plugin which adds a few linked buttons and I'm trying to add "contact us" with a mailto link as one of them but keep getting an error saying "url must be valid".

Is there a way to create a mailto url which is qualifies as valid?

Thanks

Comment: Here are some examples on how to setup a mailto url: http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/learn-mailto-syntax/6748/

Comment: @JeroenBellemans Thank you, but this field does not allow any code, only a url value. Any tips there?

Comment: which plugin you're using

Comment: @NabeelKhan It's a custom one built by the people who programmed the website. but it seems like a pretty straight forward:
"icon field"
"name field"
"link field"

Comment: I can suggest edits after seeing the plugin. let me know if you want me to

Comment: @NabeelKhan and there's not way to just create a valid mailto link? that's what I'm seeking

Comment: how're you currently creating it? mailto:name@domain.com ?

Answer (score 0):

The standard mailto link looks like this:

```
<a href=“mailto:name@domain.com”>Mail me</a>
```

However, your plugin might be using "`sanitize_url()`" function to see if you're entering a proper url (with `http://` or `https://`).

So if that's the case then you need to modify the plugin and make it sanitize_text_field or any other that fits best as per your needs. You might need to make changes to plugin at other places too along with it.